# Workaround for java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError to not show it

Tags: java

After migration to Java 8, my tool throw the follwing exception if somebody try to run it on earlier Java environments.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/myapp/MyTool: Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
```

Is there some way to not show this error, and show nice error message with proposition to upgrade Java.

As I understood I should create some small class like:

```
public class CheckerJavaVersion {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String sVersion = System.getProperty("java.version");
        sVersion = sVersion.substring(0, 3);
        Float f = Float.valueOf(sVersion);
        if (f.floatValue() < (float) 1.8) {
            System.out.println("Please upgrate your Java to 1.8 version");
            System.exit(1);
        }   
    }

}
```

and compile it via older compiler. I need some solution how to run this class firstly before the main method of MyToll class starts.

PS. Aplication is packed in jar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the error occurs when the class is loaded, so you'd either have to use a "starter app" which starts the actual application in a separate process or dynamically load the application after the Java version has been checked.

I didn't test it but what *might* work is something like this:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
  if( javaVersionOk ) {
    Class.forName("actual.mainclass.name").getMethod("actual.main.method.name").invoke();
  }
}
```

The idea is to access the class via its name and thus make the runtime load and initialize it at that time. I'm not sure, however, if you can delay class loading like that in all cases so you'd have to go on from there.

And btw, IIRC there already are applications/libraries that provide this kind of functionality, I just don't rember their names. So a search might be worth your while.

*Edit*: you might want to have a look at [appstart](https://code.google.com/p/appstart/) if not for using it then for inspiration.

Another launcher would be [Apache Commons Launcher](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-launcher/).

*Alternatives:*

Alternatively you could just provide a launch script for each platform you want to support , call `java -version` and check the returned version before launching the application.

Another alternative would be to use JNLP/WebStart locally, which allows you to specify a minimum version and which AFAIK even provides for download/upgrade functionality.